# Coding: utf-8 doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, powershell, encoding, utf-8

Utf-8 doesn't work on my computer. I tried the exact same code at another computer and it worked  but on my computer it doesn't. It's in python.

My program starts like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    # Behövs i python 2 för åäö

from Tkinter import * 

class Kryssruta(Button):
    """ Knapp som kryssas i/ur när man trycker på den """

    def __init__(self, master, nr = 0, rad = 0, kolumn = 0):
     #Konstruktor, notera master
        Button.__init__(self,master) 
        self.master = master         
        self.rad = rad
        self.kolumn = kolumn
        self.markerad = False
        self.kryssad = False
        self.cirklad = False

        self["command"] = self.kryssa

    def kryssa(self):
        if self.markerad==False: 
            self.master.klickat(self)
```

On one computer it works like a charm, but on my own computer I get the message.

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file 'blah' but no encoding declared;
see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Using a PC, running in powershell.
Anyone who knows what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Is the file actually UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I copy pasted your file and it does *not* given any error due to encodings in python2 nor 3.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? And, is the error message a precise copy-paste, or only an approximation?

Answer (score 4):

You have a (number of) blank line(s) above the `coding:` line. From [the document listed in the error message](http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html):

> > To define a source code encoding, a magic comment must
> >         be placed into the source files either as first or second
> >         line in the file, such as:

Comment: I should have noticed that "no encoding declared" in the error message before I wrote my answer. I'm sure you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

You declare that the source file is using utf-8 encoding but actually it isn't, it's using the Windows code page default for your system.

Open the file in Notepad and save it out again with Save As, setting `UTF-8` in the Encoding dropdown.

Comment: It seems it is, `'\xc3\xa4'` is utf8 encoding for `'ä'` char.

Comment: @alko, and `'\xc3'` is `Ã` in the most likely code page, which doesn't appear in the source. Also `'ö'` is `'\xc3\xb6'`. You're probably correct then.

Comment: Also, `'\xC3'` is `├` in DOS code pages 437 and 850, and `√` in the old Macintosh encoding.  These don't appear in the source either.